# Lucene vs DB index for simple search on big data?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, lucene, rdbms

I have around 500 GB of data in one table of MySQL which has around 5 billion records. It has around 15 columns. It has index on all the required columns. When I do `select * from big_table where index_column = some_value` it takes couple of minutes to return the data. There are no joins and also I do not have full text search requirement here.

I have seen some teams have used lucene(or elastic search) to solve the performance issue here which returns the records in couple of seconds.
My understanding as of now was lucene(Elastic search) are primarily used for full text search but here looks like they can be do wonders even
for simple search functionality in case of big data.

My question is how lucene index/search is performing better than DB index/search here for simple where search functionality ?

Comment: It might be that your MySQL instance needs to be configured to use more memory for its buffer pool, so the index you search fits in RAM.

Comment: @BillKarwin Does MySQL(or any other DBMS)  bring complete indexed column data(alongwith row location) in memory from disk or it first identifies the  data rows need to be fetched on the disk itself with the help of index  and then fetch only that indexed data along with their row location ?

Comment: MySQL can load a partial index into the buffer pool, as much as it needs to search it for the values you want.